# is.list always returns true on tibble columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

So, I have a tibble containing both vector- and list-columns.

Selecting list-columns is easy with dplyr:

```
select_if(tb, is.list)
```

but its negation with `!` or `-` does not work *edit, this does* `select_if(tb,function(x)!is.list(x))`

So I thought I could do something like:

```
select(tb, which(!apply(tb,2,is.list))
```

This returns **no columns**. Because apparently (here comes the reprex), `is.list` on tibble columns always returns true, even for vector columns (?).

```
df <- data.frame(A = runif(100))
tb <- tibble(A = runif(100))

is.list(df$A)
# FALSE
is.list(tb$A)
# FALSE
is.list(df[,1])
# FALSE
is.list(tb[,1])
# TRUE
```

Can anybody shed light on what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because tibble has default drop argument as `FALSE` meaning when you subset only one column from dataframe it returns a numeric vector whereas when you subset one column from tibble it returns a one-column tibble.

Check their classes.

```
class(df[, 1])
#[1] "numeric"
class(tb[, 1])
#[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

If you add `drop = FALSE` in dataframe, it will return you back a dataframe.

```
class(df[, 1, drop = FALSE])
#[1] "data.frame"
```

A dataframe/tibble column is still a list.

```
is.list(tb[, 1])
#[1] TRUE
is.list(df[, 1, drop = FALSE])
#[1] TRUE
```

So to answer your question yes, `is.list` always returns `TRUE` on tibble unless you explicitly mention `drop = TRUE` on one-column tibble.

```
is.list(tb[, 1, drop = TRUE])
#[1] FALSE
```

Comment: makes perfect sense, thanks for the detailed answer!